# SmartLock disableAutoSignIn() stopped working returning 403

Tags: google-identity, google-smartlockpasswords

Google SmartLock for web seems to have a broken disableAutoSignIn() function. This used to work but about a week ago the url the function calls to sign you out is now returning a 403 error.

https://smartlock.google.com/iframe/request?client=xxx&id=xxx&renderMode=navPopout

I am also getting this error on other sites using SmartLock such as [Hipmunk](https://www.hipmunk.com/)

https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/web/retrieve-credentials

Comment: This should be fixed now, can you verify and let us know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, this a bug on the Google side, a fix just rolled out, let us know if you still have trouble.

Comment: I am facing some issue in password sync. can you please have a look?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63830860/app-and-website-saved-password-is-not-sync